# Pdf preview not working with Lyx 2.3.7 on Windows 11

Tags: pdftex, lyx, forward-inverse-search

I have installed Lyx 2.3.7 and SumatraPdf and followed the instructions provided in [LyX 2.3 - How can I successfully set up the forward and inverse search?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473572/lyx-2-3-how-can-i-successfully-set-up-the-forward-and-inverse-search)

My Texlive version is 2023 and works without any issue. However, when I try to view the pdf of a lyx file by pressing `Document => View[pdf(pdflatex)]`, I get the error:

```
LyX: LaTeX Failed
The external program 
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1
finished with an error. It is recommended you fix the cause of the external program's error (check the logs)
```

Any tips/suggestions regarding how I can fix the issue will be much appreciated.